# Как отобразить редактируемую картинку в PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, devexpress, winforms

Создаю у редактируемого объекта свойство типа Image, Bitmap или Icon. В любом случае PropertyGrid (DevExpress'овский) отображает изображение как строку (либо "System.Drawing.Bitmap", либо "Значок").

Нехорошо. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

В дизайнере грида нужно указать тип выводимого поля - должно быть такое - если память не изменяет - Image.
И вообще смотри примеры с ними или глянь на ихнем сайте - там примеров туча...

Comment: Я нашёл только это: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ56522.aspx

Обещали поправить, но, видимо, даже в 11 версии ещё не поправили.

Comment: похоже на то...
честно сам не сталкивался с такой ситуацией.
можешь кстати попробовать VerticalGrid - если конечно он подходит под твою задачу.